# Laravel 5.1.11 Post requests not working

Tags: php, post, laravel-5

in my codes all get requests is working properly but not same for post methods.

This is work

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/info', 'UserController@info');       
});
```

This is not work

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth'], function ()
{
   Route::post('/info', 'UserController@info');   
});
```

What can be wrong ?

Comment: Please share the error

Comment: I see this error on Postman

Could not get any response

Why this might have happened:

The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly

Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General

Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy

Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

Answer (score 1):

If you are using blade in front-end, you can use `{{crf_field()}}` after opening the post form

Answer (score 0):

Your codes looks ok but that happen sometimes if the csrf token is missing in the form. You should check that.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

You are using in both routes the same controller function, you need a function for each request

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/info', 'UserController@info');       
    Route::post('/info', 'UserController@setInfo');   
});
```

post request don't return view, only alter data and do redirects

Comment: ı dont use same controller for 2 different request. In second, i just changed first one. Just show this is work and this is not work .

Comment: what do you mean by not work?, you need both routes to access the page, the get is used to render the page, the post is used to save the form from that page

Comment: im trying on Postman. I take an Json response when method is get. When method is put.  return "Could not get any response" on Postman. Some people talked about csrf_token. But i think. it is different